# Image hyperlink using a value stored in database

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to allow the user to link their facebook, twitter etc and have an image for the corresponding link appear which will take them to the link stored in the database.

The problem is, instead of giving me something like "www.facebook.com" it is giving me "http://localhost:60619/User/www.facebook.com"

right now I am using to get this.

```
<a href="@Url.Action(@Model.Facebook)">
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Facebook.gif")" alt="Facebook" /></a>
```

The Url.Action has managed to remove /User/Profile/www.facebook.com and replace is with /user/www.facebook.com but I can't get it to be just "www.facebook.com".

Edit: I have this figured out but thank you for the help! I just needed to add validation so that the user either enters http:// at the beginning or I will have it added on manually before it is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{
    var url = @Model.Facebook.Split('/');
    <a href="@url[url.Length]">...</a>

}
```

Comment: 2 things, with    .Split('/') the length always ended up being 1 but when I removed that it came out to the correct length of the stored link.

However, when it gets to      @url[url.Length] it is telling me that the index is out of range.

Just a thought, wouldn't that give me the beginning of the link as opposed to the part that I want anyways?

I do feel like this is the right direction though, thanks for getting me started!

Comment: Hey, I actually just figured out the problem. The link I had stored in the database was being read as a relative url because I did not have http:// at the start of it. I just need to add some validation to force that at the beginning of the stored value and my original code works.

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice the comments, im kinda new to that site). Anyway im glad you found the solution to your problem!

Comment: Hey @Efthimis , I have this following code, i have to add url to img src  <img alt="" src='<%# Eval("Name") %>' runat="server" />